# How to migrate backlog items from VersionOne to TFS 2012 (when details contains images)

Tags: tfs, import, migration, backlog

How to migrate backlog items from VersionOne to TFS 2012 (when details contains images)
I created an excel export but the VersionOne Description that is being imported to the TFS Work Item Details contains images.  Both products allow images.. How would you migrate the images with the workitems?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to write code against the TFS workitem API and you'll have to write code against the Version1 database. 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/10/06/more-about-creating-work-item-using-tfs-api.aspx